# What's the difference between a PageControl and an HtmlControl in WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

And in what conditions should you use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML controls intent is to merely show an existing HTML page in place with the goal of merely presenting it. With page control, you can extend it with behaviors, compose it with more page controls and have it work with your navigation model.